# Does Lightning for outlook not support Tasks?

Tags: lightning, lightning-outlook

When I started exploring Lightning for outlook I can see only Contacts and events can be synced with it. Does Lightning not support Tasks. In Salesforce classic, I can see the tasks in sync with Outlook and those are displayed in the home page tab[image]

Can I see the same with lightning as well

Answer (score 0):

yes the Lightning for outlook do supports the Tasks

[image]

For anyone who requires the answer